# Is there Any Way to Simplify this Function?

Tags: c#, refactoring, simplify

I have a function that returns a string with coordinates and the direction that the object is looking at.
But I really don't like the length of the function and I'd like to shorten it. I don't know what I could do to shorten it. Can someone help me?

The Function looks like this:

```
public string Execute(string text)
{
    var letters = text.ToCharArray().ToList();

    foreach (var letter in letters)
    {
        if (letter == 'R')
        {
            switch(direction)
            {
                case "N":
                    direction = "E";
                    break;
                case "E":
                    direction = "S";
                    break;
                case "S":
                    direction = "W";
                    break;
                case "W":
                    direction = "N";
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (letter == 'L')
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case "N":
                    direction = "W";
                    break;
                case "E":
                    direction = "N";
                    break;
                case "S":
                    direction = "E";
                    break;
                case "W":
                    direction = "S";
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (letter == 'M')
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case "N":
                    positionY++;
                    break;
                case "E":
                    positionX++;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    positionY--;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    positionX--;
                    break;
            }
        }
            
        if (letter == 'B')
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case "N":
                    positionY--;
                    break;
                case "E":
                    positionX--;
                    break;
                case "S":
                    positionY++;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    positionX++;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $"{positionX}:{positionY}:{direction}";
}
```

This Text Down here is just a useless text so I can submit my Question because my code is too long and Stackoverflow recognizes the Question as mostly code so I have to write more text without the Code Brackets to be able to submit the Question. You don't have to read this Text because it has no purpose.

Comment: Look for patterns, and figure a way to use them in an algorithm.  For example, for `R` and `L`, it looks like the directly is rotated either clockwise or counterclockwise.  You could write a small function that enables that (with an array of direction strings (that you make wrap around) and that your code moves left or right in the array).  Similarly, for `M` and `B`, you offset the positions by either `+1` or `-1` in a fixed pattern.  Refactor that logic out to a function that figures out the rule.

Comment: Use dictionaries which has old value as key and new value as the value.   Dictionary<string, string> lDict = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "N", "W" }, { "E", "N" }, { "S", "E" }, { "W", "S" } };  dict = lDict[dict];

Comment: In my opinion, this is exactly the right approach. Although this might be a few more code line that "smart" solutions, it is the easierst to maintain and understand. For every other solution proposed here so far, you will have a hard time if you or someone else must change it later. Instead, everyone will understand the simple "switch" approach instantly.

Answer (score 0):

I realize OP may not be interested in an answer to this anymore, but I'll share my thoughts nonetheless.

[Switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) were introduced in C# 8.0, and they may be used to simplify/shorten (parts of) your code.

The `switch` statements in the first two `if` loops of your function may be directly replaced with `switch` expressions. The replacement for the `switch` statement in the first `if` loop would be as follows:

```
if (letter == 'R')
{   
    direction = direction switch
    {
        "N" => "E", // interpretation: if the current direction is "N", assign "E"
        "E" => "S",
        "S" => "W",
        "W" => "N",
        _ => direction // discard pattern to provide a default value in case there is no match
    };
}
```

The `switch` statement in the second `if` loop may be replaced in a similar fashion.

---

To shorten your code further, you could *consider* including [case guards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression#case-guards) in your `switch` expressions.

**But:** When introducing case guards, reading and interpreting the `switch` expression generally requires more effort. As @Heinz Kessler comments above, "smart" coding for the sake of having fewer code lines is not worth sacrificing the readability and maintainability of the code for.

In case of interest/curiosity, [here is a working DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SZIvdu) of how your code *could* be implemented using `switch` expressions with case guards. To achieve this, I have changed the logic in the `Execute` method. For readability (this may be a personal preference), changes such as variable renaming and introducing constants have also been made.

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
           string text = "";
            var letters = text.ToCharArray().ToList();
            Dictionary<char, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new Dictionary<char, Dictionary<string, string>>() {
                {'R', new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "N", "E" }, { "E", "S" }, { "S", "W" }, { "W", "N" }}},
                {'L', new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "N", "W" }, { "E", "N" }, { "S", "E" }, { "W", "S" }}},
                {'M', new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "N", "AY" }, { "E", "AX" }, { "S", "SY" }, { "W", "SX" }}},
                {'R', new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "N", "SY" }, { "E", "SX" }, { "N", "AY" }, { "N", "AX" }}}
            };
            string direction = "";
            int positionX = 0;
            int positionY = 0;

            foreach (var letter in letters)
            {
                string value = dict[letter][direction];
                switch (value)
                {
                    case "SX":
                        positionX--;
                        break;
                    case "SY":
                        positionY--;
                        break;
                    case "AX":
                        positionX++;
                        break;
                    case "AY":
                        positionY++;
                        break;
                    case "N":
                        direction = value;
                        break;
                    case "E":
                        direction = value;
                        break;
                    case "S":
                        direction = value;
                        break;
                    case "W":
                        direction = value;
                        break;
                }
```